# Need The Best Approach to this Mysql PHP Date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to this.

In my mysql table, called "news", I have a `Date` field. That field has dates stored in the usual format (YYYY-MM-DD).

What I need is for fields in that table, to go from this in the mysql news table:

```
2007-04-12
2007-02-23
2006-11-16
```

To this in html:

```
2007-
April
February
2006 -
November
```

I guess I'd query for all the years, then for each year, query for all the months.

Any pointers or ideas are appreciated

Comment: You need a PHP solution or mysql query level solution

Comment: PHP solution is appreciated but I think mysql solution will be more robust

Comment: Closers: Please don't close as "minimal understanding", OP is not asking for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$sql="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y') AS `Year`, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%M') AS `Month` FROM `news` GROUP BY `Year`,`Month` ORDER BY `Date` DESC";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$p_year="";
while($out=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    if($out['Year']!=$p_year){
        $p_year=$out['Year'];echo "<br>".$p_year;
    }
    echo "<br> - ".$out['Month'];
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Query once, and divide into sub-arrays when processing the rows (usually in the form of `while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`).

Note that I assumed you use PDO, because that's what you *should* be using.